# When manually opening source files, the project name isn't shown in the path

Tags: eclipse, stm32cubeide

everyone!

I'm running into a problem that is affecting my ability to fully utilize the indexer in Eclipse, specifically the STM32CubeIDE port of Eclipse.

If a source file is automatically opened (like when I pause execution on a microcontroller), the full path of the file is noted in the hovertext for the tab (i.e. "PROJECT_NAME/source/filename.c").

If a source file is manually opened (such as when I double click on it), the path shown is relative to the project (i.e. "source/filename.c").

The consequence of that is that I can't utilize indexing in manually opened files. I get an error that says, "Could not find symbol 'blah' in index."

Is there a setting somewhere that causes all opened files to include their full path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have something wrong with your project. It works for me without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I hadn't looked close enough at the icons in the Project Explorer. My "source" directory was actually a Project, not a Folder.

I created a Folder named source, copied everything there, then deleted the source Project.